# Unable to fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: 12.04, xorg, security, gnome-terminal, x11-forwarding

frequently getting 'fork: Cannot allocate memory' when running commands over ssh. I have 64Gb of RAM and usually 1~2Gb free. 
swap is more than 8gb free

Ubuntu version:"Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS" Desktop 64 bit

free -m output:

```
   total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:         64386      64079        307          0       9840      41196
-/+ buffers/cache:      13042      51343
Swap:         7720        347       7373

ulimit -a output :

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 514954
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 514954
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Thanks